# how to change many textview color on button click

Tags: android

how to change textview color on button click

```
mBtn = ((Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 ));
mBtn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));
   }
});
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? Crash?

Comment: have you heard about selectors ?

Comment: your changing button color instead of textview color.. check your code.

Comment: Try to use Color.parseColor(yourColorHashCode);

Answer (score 6):

You missed *#* in color code.

```
mTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `TextView#setTextColor()` does not have an overload that takes a String parameter.

Comment: i thing have to use color.parse color

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this too

```
mTV.setTextColor(Color.parse("#FF00FF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To change TextView background color use

```
mTv.setBackgroundColor()
```

and to change text color use

```
mTv.setTextColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in your onClick()

```
int count = 10;
TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
   textViewArray[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
   textViewArray[i].setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.light_sky_blue));
}
```

Comment: from where array came in picture?

Comment: is it mentioned that TextViews are maintaining by Arrays? *i can't find that please help me in that*

Comment: If he wants to change so many textviws' property then maintaining array is good option I guess

Comment: i don't think so. OP had not mentioned that TextViews are dynamically generated. let it be. hope answer is helpful

Comment: If he doesn't want to generate textview dynamically he can pass their Ids